# Is brute force ever fastest for the travelling salesman problem, and if so up to what number of locations?

Tags: graph-theory, optimization, algorithms

I'm writing an article and want to say something about the travelling salesman problem. I'm trying to find out if brute force can ever be the best approach.

On wikipedia, it mentions "the Held–Karp algorithm that solves the problem in time O(n^2 2^n)" whereas brute force is O(n!)

I'm particularly interested in problems with a small number of locations. For example, with 6 locations, brute force is 6! = 720, whereas Held-Karp, by the above formula is 64 * 36 = 2304.

Is brute force then the fastest algorithm up to a certain number of locations, or can something else beat 6! with 6 locations (actually, I think it's only 6!/2 because half of the routes are just going in the opposite direction)?

Many thanks!

Comment: It's $\mathrm{O}(n!)$, which is different than needing $n!$ operations.

Comment: @MorganRodgers Thanks, yes I'm informally ignoring the difference between O() and the actual number of operations. Given how few operations are needed to test a route with the brute force approach, I think it's a fair assumption that if no other algorithm can beat O(n!) with 6 locations, then no other algorithm will take less operations, since the brute force approach needs so few operations for each route. I'm really just trying to figure out if it's fair to say "At 6 locations, brute force is fastest".

Comment: Indeed there are "polynomial time" algorithms where the implicit constant is so large that they are not competitive with simpler exponential time algorithms until the problem size gets to be impractically large.  So one sense of this Question is to ask if something of that kind hinders implementation of the [Held-Karp algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Held%E2%80%93Karp_algorithm).

Comment: When there are 2 locations, Brute goes from A to B and wins.

Comment: @EdPegg:  Does it?  The Held-Karp algorithm asks us to solve the shortest path problem for each "subproblem", starting with the smallest subsets of vertices.  If there are only two locations (vertices), then there is only one subproblem for the symmetric version of the TSP and two (each direction) for the asymmetric version.  In any case the tour is required to "return to the starting point."

Comment: Right. But brute force is a simple "try everything", so it's slightly faster than Held-Karp in this instance.